# Dialogflow: Interactive Canvas giving error

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to run sample code for Interactive Canvas in Dialogflow but it's giving me the error.

Followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/actions/interactivecanvas/build/action

```
app.intent('welcome', (conv) => {
  conv.ask('Welcome! Do you want me to change color or pause spinning?');
  conv.ask(new ImmersiveResponse({
    url: 'https://www.google.com',
  }));
});
```

Here is the package.json file content:

```
{
"name": "canvas-sample-functions",
  "description": "Actions on Google Immersive Canvas Sample Functions",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.7.0-preview.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is "TypeError: ImmersiveResponse is not a constructor."

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not using the preview version of the Actions on Google client library. The package.json dependency should be:

```
"actions-on-google": "preview",
```

You should be using your own web app for the canvas URL. In particular you need to ensure that the web app will work with the restrictions places on canvas web apps: https://developers.google.com/actions/interactivecanvas/build/web-app#restrictions

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, I have updated the question with package.json file content, you can see that I am using "preview" and it's still giving the same error.